# checkbox textview just work in emulator android

Tags: android

I have problem , my checkboxed textview just work checked when click in emulator , but if i try on device , my checkboxed textview not checked when click , just blank .

My Adapter :

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.id.nirwana.R;
import com.nirwana.app.models.Amenities;

public class AmenitiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Amenities> implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Context context;
    private int itemLayoutResource;
    Spinner spinner;
    String[] menus;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public AmenitiesAdapter(Context context, int itemLayoutResource,
            ArrayList<Amenities> items, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(context, itemLayoutResource, items);
        this.itemLayoutResource = itemLayoutResource;
        this.context = context;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(this.itemLayoutResource, null);
        }
        Amenities amenities = getItem(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(amenities.getName());
        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbox);
        if (cbox != null) {
            if (amenities.getChecked()) {
                cbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                cbox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My Xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/title_item"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />



</LinearLayout>
```

My Dialog :

```
package com.nirwana.app.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.id.nirwana.R;
import com.nirwana.app.adapters.AmenitiesAdapter;
import com.nirwana.app.interfaces.SelectAmenitiesComunicator;
import com.nirwana.app.models.Amenities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class SelectAmenitiesDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ArrayList<Amenities> amenities;
    ArrayList<Amenities> selectedAmenities;
    SelectAmenitiesComunicator listener;

    public SelectAmenitiesDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SelectAmenitiesDialog(ArrayList<Amenities> amenities) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.amenities = amenities;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        listener = (SelectAmenitiesComunicator) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        selectedAmenities = new ArrayList<Amenities>();
        AmenitiesAdapter amenitiesAdapter = new AmenitiesAdapter(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.amenities_item_layout,
                amenities, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        ListView list = new ListView(getActivity());
        list.setAdapter(amenitiesAdapter);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbox);
                if (cbox.isChecked()) {
                    amenities.get(arg2).setChecked(false);
                    selectedAmenities.remove(amenities.get(arg2));
                } else {
                    amenities.get(arg2).setChecked(true);
                    selectedAmenities.add(amenities.get(arg2));
                }
                ;
            }
        });

        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.select_amenities))
                .setView(list)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_label,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (!selectedAmenities.isEmpty()) {
                            listener.getAmenities(selectedAmenities);
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo6qY.jpg)

Comment: try this add in to checkbox xml....  android:checked="true"

Comment: try this xml.....                     <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/cbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
  android:checked="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

Comment: do u want the checkbox to be clicked on click of textview??

Comment: not work brother ,, -_- still uncheck when i click textview .

Comment: Muthu : yes , i do ,, on emulator , its work , but on my device or other doesn't work .